# Javascript to change class of an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is heavily trimmed down source code from a webpage I'm working on right now.

```
<!--// GRID ENTRY //-->
    <li class="entry" id="sjDDulC8wt">
        <div class="entry_actions">
            <ul class="entry_actions">
                <li class='have_it'>
<a href='javascript: haveItem("name", "id", "none")'  target='_self' title='Have It' class='have_it'>%</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Inside the `haveItem()` function I'm trying to change the class of the `<a>` element from 'have_it' to 'have_it selected' to change the appearance of the element. The reason for the id is because I have dozens of these elements on the page. The javascript I'm currently using is:

```
var targetA = document.getElementbyID(sjDDulC8wt).getElementsbyTitle("Have_it"); 
targetA.removeClass("have_it").addClass("have_it selected");
```

When I click the link, the `haveItem()` function runs, but it doesn't change the class. How can I change my script so that clicking the link will change the class?

Comment: `getElementsbyTitle` ... is that real?

Comment: There are no such functions as `removeClass` and `addClass` in JavaScript. Neither does `getElementsByTitle` exist. I usually hesitate to reply with "use jQuery", but **use jQuery**. This is the kind of thing it really excels at. Your code would boil down to `$('#sjDDulC8wt [title=Have_it]').addClass('selected')`.

Comment: You have several problems here: (1) put the id in quotes in getElementByID. (2) getElementsByTitle does not exist. (3) even if it did exist, your second line is trying to perform single element operations on an array. (4) even if that worked, the functions addClass and removeClass don't exist. You could fix all of these problems by using jQuery.

Comment: @meagar, Ben Lee: There is `.classList.add()`. He wants HTML5, so may he use it :-)

Comment: Huh, it pulled up results on google. I guess it shows that I haven't worked with Javascript in over a year. I tried to get the second element from getElementbyClassName too, but that didn't work either. I have JQuery installed but I'm not familiar with it. @meagar I just tried your code with and without quotes around the id but I'm not having any luck with it.

Comment: @meager - Um... There *is* those 2 functions in JavaScript. `element.classList.add` and `.remove` and `.toggle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are using jQuery since you are using `removeClass()` and `addClass`. Otherwise, I would recommend you link to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) so that the code below works, or stick with only JavaScript.

```
var targetA = $('#sjDDulC8wt .have_it');
targetA.addClass('selected');
```

For future reference, here are some things about your code that you can improve:

1. `getElementById()` accepts the id of the element you want to retrieve as a string. Basically, you should wrap your ID in `'` or `"`
2. Be careful where you are putting spaces and underscores. They are not the same thing. Your list item has the title `Have It`, while your JavaScript has `Have_it`.
3. Capitalization matters. `Have_It` is not the same thing as `Have_it`. Be careful with this when you try to get elements by ID.
4. A class with spaces in it is actually multiple classes. `have_it selected` actually has both the `have_it` class and the `selected` class. Therefore it not necessary to remove `have_it` and then add `have_it selected` - you can go straight to adding the `selected` class.
5. The function `getElementbyTitle()` does not currently exist in JavaScript. Also, be careful again about capitalization. Typically, the first letter of every word in a function is capitalized. Thus, if it did exist it would be called `getElementByTitle()` (notice the `B` instead of `b`).

Comment: I wasn't aware that those functions were JQuery only, the links I found them on made no reference to JQuery from what I saw. I'll go ahead and add the tag for anyone else who stumbles across this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
var anchor = document.querySelector( '#sjDDulC8wt [title="Have It"]' );
if ( anchor ) anchor.classList.add( 'selected' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/UZfnh/

(Won't work in older browsers.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use jQuery then you can change the classname of an element using [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className):

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementId");
element.className = "have_it selected";
```

Note also this function: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) (HTML5).

As has been pointed out, you have some other issues selecting your element. From your example, it looks like you want to use:

```
var element = document.getElementById("sjDDulC8wt");
var children = element.getElementsByClassName("have_it");
children[0].className = "have_it selected";
```

Note that there's **no error handling/null checks** here. And this handles a simple case of only changing the first child with the specified class, assuming that it exists.

But prefer jQuery if you can use that. From your use of `addClass/removeClass` it appears that you already expect jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the task for you:

```
<a title="Have It" class="have_it" onclick="this.className+=' selected'">%</a>
```

However, you should learn about the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/). None of the methods you used (`getElementbyID`, `getElementsbyTitle`, `removeClass` and `addClass`) exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully find the element, you can do one of these:

1. `element.classList.add("selected");`

   It uses a fairly new [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) feature available for FF 3.6, IE 10, Chrome 8, Opera 11.50, Safari 5.1 and above. It the the most preferred way to do it once you are sure your clients will have one of those browsers (near future).
2. `element.className += " selected";`

   [`className` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className). This works and is probably the easiest way. Not so nice as the `classList` thing, but available for all browsers.